# Asp.net MVC error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, viewmodel

I am getting the error :

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album] ToPagedList[Album](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcMusicStore.Models.Album], Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression*

For my following controller action :

```
    public ActionResult Browse(string genre, int?page)
    {
        // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
        int pageIndex = page ?? 1;
        var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Where(g => g.Name == genre)
                                       .Select(g => new GenreAlbumView
                                       {
                                           ID = g.GenreId,
                                           Name = g.Name,
                                           Albums = g.Albums.ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize)
                                       }).SingleOrDefault();
        return View(genreModel);
    }
```

What can be the reason and solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run your genermodel query:

```
var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Where(g => g.Name == genre).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then run your select.

Because lin2entity has limited functionality support and can't convert your function:

```
g.Albums.ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize)
```

to appropriated sql command, in fact it can't create related expression tree for it, so you should first get entities and then select as a way you want.

If you should do such a paging in DB, create a stored procedure and use it.

Comment: Thanks bro but I am unsure which answer to mark as accepted :-) . Both of the answers work and i don't know which performs better.

Comment: @Pankaj hope this helped you if both answer has equal value for you flip the coin :)

Comment: LOL...I marked this as answer becoz it looks a better approach. And also, i don't find any reason or situation when one should use prefer skip and take over this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that th ToPagedList method is not something that can be translated to a SQL query and executed in the database.

For paging on the database server you can use the methods Skip and Take.

Try the following:

```
var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Where(g => g.Name == genre)
                                       .Select(g => new GenreAlbumView
                                       {
                                           ID = g.GenreId,
                                           Name = g.Name,
                                           Albums = g.Albums.Skip(PageSize * (PageIndex -1)).Take(PageSize)
                                       }).SingleOrDefault();
```

When you use Skip/Take which can be translated into a sql command, the paging will be done on the database server but when you first execute the query and then call the ToPagedList method you will have a performance hit. The paging is then executed in memory over all the Albums that are already loaded from the database.

This principle has to do with what Linq calls Deffered Execution. 
You are building an Expression Tree that is only translated in SQL when you 'execute' the expression tree (with for example Single,ToList,First,Count or similar methods) the Sql command is generated and executed on the database server.

So if you first call 'ToList' and then call the paging you will fetch all records from the database and page them in memory which will be a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks mate for touching the deeper issue and making me understand why was that happening.

Comment: Sorry mate i marked the Saeed answer as accepted coz it looked clean coding and better approach. But, can you help me understand any situation when one prefers or needs to use skip/take over the Saeed's approach.